# Perl String::Approx for values that taken from MySQL DataBase

Tags: perl

When I apply [String::Approx](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3A%3AApprox) to the values taken from the database, it doesn't check the matching words.

The program is as follows...

```
use String::Approx qw (amatch);
my @matches = qw();
my %matchhash = qw();
my @x=$search_keyword;
my $i=0;
my $j=0;
my $l=1;
my $qry1="SELECT * FROM AuctionCategoriesName";
my $prp1 = $dbh1->prepare($qry1);
$prp1->execute();
while(my $row1=$prp1->fetchrow_hashref())
{
    $y=$row1->{'Name'};
    @name="(['$y'])";
    @match = grep { amatch (@x, @$_) } @name;
    $cnt=$#match;
    if($cnt < 1)
    {
        $matches[$i]=$match[0];
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Connections to db are perfect.

I want to get the approximately matched names from db amoung all the values present in the `$row1->{'Name'}`. The values must be kept stored in `$matches[$i]`. I call those values as:

```
foreach my $k (@matches) { print "$k <br/>" }
```

Comment: You appear to be setting @name to a string, which makes no sense to me. Boil the problem down to the minimum amount of code to reproduce it and you'll probably find the answer yourself.

Comment: It is because i found an example as `**@poss = (['rat'],['gnat'],['giraffe'],['dig'],['catatonic'],['care'],['catre'],['hawk']);**` so to make the content as similar, I did it so. It will be great If you have a better suggestion in usage of `**String::Approx**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Richard said this line is unnecessary :-

```
@name="(['$y'])";
```

You could write $y as is and perl does the right thing.

The grep followed by the if is duplication of the same work. amatch returns true/false in scalar context so we can use that.

You could simplify your code along these lines :-

```
  1 use String::Approx qw (amatch);
  2 use strict;
  3 my @matches = qw();
  4 my $search_keyword = 'Hello';
  5 foreach my $y ('hello', 'world')
  6 {
  7     if (amatch ($search_keyword, ($y)))
  8     {
  9         push @matches, $y;
 10     }
 11 }
 12 
 13 print @matches
```

The output is :-

```
$ perl test.pl
hello
```